# Getting list of nodes for user

Tags: permissions, jackrabbit, jcr, jcr-sql2

I have many 'nt:folder' `Node`s created and upon each folder creation, permissions has been granted to different set of users. 
Now I need to get list of nodes based on user(with read and write) persmissions.

Using jackrabbit 2.6.0

Partial snippet of user creation and privieges assignement:

- **User creation**

```
    UserManager userManager = ((JackrabbitSession) session).getUserManager(); 
    org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.user.User user =
    (org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.user.User)userManager.getAuthorizable(userName);
```

- **Add entry**

```
    javax.jcr.security.Privilege[] privileges = new
      javax.jcr.security.Privilege[] {
        accessControlManager.privilegeFromName(javax.jcr.security.Privilege.JCR_WRITE)
      };
```

- **Temporary folder access**

```
    Map<String, Value> restrictions = new HashMap<String, Value>(); 
    restrictions.put("rep:nodePath",
      valueFactory.createValue(userDbInstance.getUserFilePath(),
      PropertyType.PATH));  restrictions.put("rep:glob",
      valueFactory.createValue("*"));
    accessControlList.addEntry(userPrincipal, privileges, true  /*allow or deny */, restrictions);
```

- **Adding Node**

  ```
  public Node addNode(String parent, String name, ETNodeTypes type) throws JCRServiceException { 
    checkSession(); 
    try { 
      name = Text.escapeIllegalJcrChars(name); 
      logger.debug("Adding Node: " + parent + "  type: " + type + "  name(escaped):" + name); 
      Node node = session.getNode(parent).addNode(name, type.getName()); 
      node.addMixin("rep:AccessControllable"); 
      logger.debug("Node added: " + node.getPath()); 
      return node; 
    } catch (RepositoryException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        throw new JCRServiceException(e,e.getMessage(),"Unable to create"); 
    } 
  }
  ```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I recently posted on answering a similar question: [Using JCR-SQL2 for querying ACLs in a Jackrabbit repository](http://dev-answers.blogspot.com.au/2014/06/using-jcr-sql2-for-querying-acls-in.html).

This was my example query:

```
select resource.*, ace.*
from [nt:hierarchyNode] as resource
inner join [rep:ACL] as acl
   ON ISCHILDNODE(acl, resource)
inner join [rep:ACE] as ace
   ON ISCHILDNODE(ace, acl)
where ace.[rep:principalName] = 'username'
```

Comment: try to execute your query, getting error.
Error ---- javax.jcr.RepositoryException: This query result contains more than one selector

Code Snippet:

String sqlStatement1 = "select resource.*, ace.* from [nt:hierarchyNode] as resource inner join [rep:ACL] as acl ON ISCHILDNODE(acl, resource) " +
            " inner join [rep:ACE] as ace ON ISCHILDNODE(ace, acl) where ace.[rep:principalName] = 'testPrincipal' ";
     
Query query = queryManager.createQuery(sqlStatement1, Query.JCR_SQL2);

QueryResult result = query.execute();
NodeIterator nodeIterator1 = result.getNodes();

Comment: The issue is your `NodeIterator nodeIterator1 = result.getNodes();` call - there are two selectors in my example query - to give you values from both `nt:hierarchyNode` and `rep:ACE`. Change the query to be just `resource.*` to avoid the error. If you wanted both resource and principal details in the results, keep the query as-is and use `result.getRows()`. For each row you could get at the node via `getNode('selectorName')`.